# Managing content that is not a post or a page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I am using advanced custom fields to manage content by posts (books) or page (home, contact, etc.). However, what if I wanted to manage content that cannot be organized by post or by page, like hours of operation, business name, slogan, logo, etc.

These fields may appear multiple times throughout the site, on the header, footer, about page, contact pages, homepage, etc. These fields aren't really a post type and creating the same custom fields for each page would be redundant.

Is there a way to manage content with ACF without organizing the content by post or page?

Something like:

```
$fields = get_fields('general_info'); //not a page, not a post
echo $fields->site_name; //appears on every page
echo $fields->slogan; //appears on 70% of pages
echo $fields->logo; //appears on header, footer and about
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACF's options pages are a great way to handle this. First you register the options page in functions.php, something like -

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'title' => 'Theme Options',
        'parent' => 'options-general.php',
        'capability' => 'manage_options'
    ));

}
```

This will place a new page under Settings in the WP menu. Then you can add fields to this options page and retrieve them in your theme with `get_field('field_name', 'option');`

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/

Comment: Great answer - I never actually knew about that feature within ACF. The plugin never ceases to amaze me with it's functionality!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Customize Screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Customize_Screen), that is native. You just have to hook a function to `customize_register` action and inside that create sections and settings/controls, something like this:

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_section('custom_footer', array(
       'title'    => 'Footer',
       'priority' => 125,
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting('copyright', array(
        'default'        => '',
        'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',   
    )); 
    $wp_customize->add_control('copyright', array(
        'label'      => 'Copyright',
        'section'    => 'custom_footer',
        'settings'   => 'copyright',
    ));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register');
```

To use the values you just have to call

```
get_theme_mod('copyright');
```

Hope it helps!